Show zero value if result is NA in query google sheet

It showed #N/A if "Cash" is not in list.
How can I show result "Cash is: 0" instead of #NA?

wrap your formula into =IFNA(your_formula_here; 0)

I want to show two columns. Column 1: "Cash is" , Column2:  0

=IFNA(your_formula_here; {"cash is:"\ 0}) or =IFNA(your_formula_here, {"cash is:", 0})

=IFNA(<formula>, {"Cash is", 0})

Or equivalent:
=IFNA(<formula>, HSTACK("Cash is", 0))

Outside North America
If you are in a region that uses comma , as the decimal separator:
=IFNA(<formula>; {"Cash is"/ 0})

Or equivalent:
=IFNA(<formula>; HSTACK("Cash is"; 0))

IFNA    HSTACK
